# Wordpress: Editing pages with another editor

Tags: wordpress

Relatively simple question, but I can't find the answer: How can I edit static pages (or posts) with my own editor instead of using WordPress? I'm not asking about the details of how to FTP, but instead where can I actually find the pages I created using WordPress in the WordPress directory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The content of the pages you create are stored in the mySQL database rather than as static files so you cannot just *see* them if you look through the directory. The software reads out the data from the db when requested and renders it according to various settings.

As for editing your wordpress pages/entries using an external editor, wordpress supports an [XML RPC interface](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support) which can be used to communicate with it. For an example of an emacs extension to edit WP articles, check out http://www.tolchz.net/2008/01/06/posting-to-wordpress-with-emacs-webloggerel/. I'm sure many other editors have this facility as well (including, I'm led to believe, Microsoft Word).

Finally, if you want to use the web interface but use your own editor for the textboxes where you edit pages/articles, check out the [it's all text](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4125) plugin for Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Live Writer is an excellent editor for this purpose. The latest version (2011) surprisingly better than the first, which was already more than I expected for a freebie, and a small project team.

Make sure you avoid all the extra "Live" options and just leave the Writer checked for install. And in WP admin settings, enable XML RPC.

Comment: There's also `Ecto` and `Blogo` for Mac users.

Answer (score -1):

wp generates dynamic pages - that means the pages only exist the moment they are requested. You would first need to "statify" them - simply downlowding would do, but there's also plugins that can do this.. Usually needed for optimizing speed/cache

Looking for "wordpress static pages plugin" might help..

PS: this would do the job of making wp 'static'
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/really-static/

Comment: -1 As per the other answers, there are ways of doing this without making the whole site static.

Comment: Well - ok - but still the question was actually about static pages:
"How can I edit static pages (or posts) with my own editor instead of using WordPress?" But thanks for rating my comment anyways..=/